Horror Movie about a Possessed Mom and Red Lights ...?
This description may not be 100% accurate, but I'm curious of the movie:
There is a mother, older daughter and son who lived in a house and the mother was possessed. The son was forced into staying at his sister's and her boyfriend's house because of the ill mother. She may have been suffering from depression. There were red lights and it was located above a store.
There is a crazy ending where the house burns down or she kills somebody.

Welcome to Movies & TV! We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title

why is this question closed ? isnt this a completely valid identify the movie question ?

The description sounds very much like 'Lights Out (2016 film)'

Rebecca, lives away from her mother Sophie and half-brother Martin. Sophie suffers from mental illness and a depression that has resurfaced, talking to an imaginary friend. One night, Martin sees Sophie talking to a figure and is horrified, he runs into his bedroom and hears scratching at his door and the door knob being turned. The next morning the nurse sees Martin and that was it something is wrong. She tries calling his mom but the mom doesn't answer. She finally calls Rebecca who comes in with her boyfriend to the school to pick up Martin.

not in the description but the kid goes and lives with his sister and her boyfriend. The Mom kills herself in the end.
Link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lights_Out_(2016_film)

that was it, thank you!!!!!

please male this your accepted answer then so that the next person knows this is it. (dont know if i can add a comment asking you to accept)
